# getting error while download the file in mvc2

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2, download

In my site, i gave **download** option to download the file. when i am checking in local server it is working properly. But after deploy the server, if i click the link means it will show the following error,

```
This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.
```

**My code here**

```
 public ActionResult Download(string fileName)
      {
         string pfn = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Files/" + fileName);
         if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pfn))
         {
             //throw new ArgumentException("Invalid file name or file not exists!");

             return Json(new JsonActionResult { Success = false, Message = "Invalid file name or file not exists!" });
         }
         else
         {

             return new BinaryContentResult()
             {
                 FileName = fileName,
                 ContentType = "application/octet-stream",
                 Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pfn)
             };
         }


     }
```

This is my code. I don't know what mistake here, Can anyone find my problem and tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with ur code is that u r missing 'JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet' while returning json.

```
  public ActionResult Download(string fileName)
  {
     string pfn = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Files/" + fileName);
     if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pfn))
     {
         //throw new ArgumentException("Invalid file name or file not exists!");

         return Json(new JsonActionResult { Success = false, Message = "Invalid file name or file not exists!" },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
     }
     else
     {

         return new BinaryContentResult()
         {
             FileName = fileName,
             ContentType = "application/octet-stream",
             Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pfn)
         };
     }


 }
```