# JsonRequestBehavior Error When downloading file from WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

A similar question was asked here:
[getting error while download the file in mvc2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256897/getting-error-while-download-the-file-in-mvc2)
but has one answer which doesn't solve my problem and I doubt it solved the problem for the other person...

Here's my problem:
I am trying to expose documents whether pdf, xlsx, tif, or any type through WebAPI and here's my current code on the API:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Download(string documentId, string contactId)
    {
        var path = DocumentSource + "\\";
        var document = DocumentDomain.GetDocument(new Guid(contactId), new Guid(documentId));

        if (ReferenceEquals(document, null) && ReferenceEquals(document.FileName, null))
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        else
        {

            try
            {
                MemoryStream responseStream = new MemoryStream();
                Stream fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path,
                document.PortfolioId == null ? "" : document.PortfolioId.ToString(), document.FileName), FileMode.Open);
                bool fullContent = true;
                if (this.Request.Headers.Range != null)
                {
                    fullContent = false;

                    RangeItemHeaderValue range = this.Request.Headers.Range.Ranges.First();


                    // From specified, so seek to the requested position.
                    if (range.From != null)
                    {
                        fileStream.Seek(range.From.Value, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                        // In this case, actually the complete file will be returned.
                        if (range.From == 0 && (range.To == null || range.To >= fileStream.Length))
                        {
                            fileStream.CopyTo(responseStream);
                            fullContent = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (range.To != null)
                    {
                        // 10-20, return the range.
                        if (range.From != null)
                        {
                            long? rangeLength = range.To - range.From;
                            int length = (int)Math.Min(rangeLength.Value, fileStream.Length - range.From.Value);
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
                            fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
                            responseStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }
                        // -20, return the bytes from beginning to the specified value.
                        else
                        {
                            int length = (int)Math.Min(range.To.Value, fileStream.Length);
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
                            fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
                            responseStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }
                    }
                    // No Range.To
                    else
                    {
                        // 10-, return from the specified value to the end of file.
                        if (range.From != null)
                        {
                            if (range.From < fileStream.Length)
                            {
                                int length = (int)(fileStream.Length - range.From.Value);
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
                                fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
                                responseStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // No Range header. Return the complete file.
                else
                {
                    fileStream.CopyTo(responseStream);
                }
                fileStream.Close();
                responseStream.Position = 0;

                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                response.StatusCode = fullContent ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
                response.Content = new StreamContent(responseStream);
                return response;
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException( HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }
```

I then have a separate MVC application, and I have the following code in a controller , that tries to download the specified documents:

```
public ActionResult DownloadDocument(string documentId, string documentName)
    {
        var currentMember = Members.GetCurrentMember();
        if (currentMember != null)
        {
            var contactId = currentMember.GetProperty("contactID").Value.ToString();
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIBaseUrl"] + "/api/document/downloadExcel?documentId=" + documentId + "&contactId=" + contactId);
                //req.Method = "GET";
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

                byte[] data;
                using (Stream s = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    data = StreamToByteArray(s);                        
                }


                var mimeType = System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(documentName);
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + documentName);

                return File(data, mimeType); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { Message = ex.ToString() });
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The following is the error that I am getting, and I am positive it has nothing to do with JsonRequestBehaviour as suggested, since I am not returning json from the API:

> This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be
>   disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request.
>   To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [InvalidOperationException: This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when
> ```
>
> this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set
>   JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +292    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +321    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +185
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +40
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +70
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +37
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +62
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +37    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +70
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +37
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +40    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +38
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9765121    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Answer (score 0):

You are returning Json in the catch section of try catch block in your MVC application at `DownloadDocument` action. That is probably why you are getting the error.

Try

```
return Json(new { Message = ex.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I think what he is asking is whether it is possible to set the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` if the return object is `File()`